# How to split form to two columns?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    path = 'images' + str(datetime.now().year) + '/' + str(datetime.now().month)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=path, null=True)
    recommended = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    promoted = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    title = models.TextField(blank = True)
    intro = RichTextField(config_name='full_ck', blank = True)
    text = RichTextField(config_name='full_ck', blank = True)
```

, form:

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Post.objects.all(), widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

and template:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<formset>
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.is_hidden %}
        {{ field }}
    {% else %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
             {% if field.errors %}<div class="errorbox">{% endif %}
                <p>{{ field.label_tag }}</p>
                <p>{{ field }}{% block formextrafields %}{% endblock %}</p>
                <p></p>
            {% if field.errors %}<p>{{ field.errors }}</p></div>{% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</formset>
</table>
```

But I want to divide form to two columns. In first may be intro, text and title fields and in second others. How to do it?

Comment: This is a hunch. You can try grouping fields in your view with http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Answer (score 6):

I use this in view:

```
form = list(form)
```

, in model I set order with:

```
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = (my fields in order)
```

and in template:

```
<!-- first -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<formset>
{% for field in form|slice:":3" %}
    [...]
{% endfor %}
</formset>
</table>

<!-- second -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<formset>
{% for field in form|slice:"3:" %}
    [...]
{% endfor %}
</formset>
</table>
```

And it works.

Comment: And It works indeed, I've been looking for this through a whole project and I avoided working with forms because they seemed bland, and here the answer was just in front of my eyes thank you stranger.

Answer (score 1):

You could use crispy forms for the layout and to add css classes: https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms